# Oceanic water mass predictor?

Tags: oceanography

Anybody know of software or a website out there that will try to predict the oceanic water mass based on temperature and salinity data? As you might due visually with a T-S diagram?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for guidance in the Earth science community?